# Vertical calendar using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want  to make a vertical navigation and display date and day for the current week inside it using angularjs so that when I click on the navigation div it alerts me the selected date.

I tried it in plunker with different templates but wasn't able to achieve it.

https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=kitchen-sink

Please have a look at the above template.This is way too complex, all I need is the "week" dates to be displayed and no events as in the template.

Please help me develop a simpler version of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
function displayCalendar(){
 var calendardate = document.getElementById("txtDate").value;
// alert(calendardate);
   var toeknisedate= calendardate.split("-");
 //alert('onchange');
 var htmlContent ="";
 var FebNumberOfDays ="";
 var counter = 1;
 
 
 var dateNow = new Date();
 var month = dateNow.getMonth();

 var nextMonth = month+1; //+1; //Used to match up the current month with the correct start date.
 var prevMonth = month -1;
 if(!document.getElementById("txtDate").value)
 {
 //alert('if')
 var day = dateNow.getDate();
 var uplimit=day+5;
 var downlimit=day-5;

 }
 else
 {
 //alert('else')
 
 var day=parseInt(toeknisedate[2]);
 var uplimit=day+5;
 var downlimit=day-5;
 
 }
 counter=downlimit;
 var weekday=dateNow.getDay();
 var year = dateNow.getFullYear();
// alert(day);
 
 
 //alert(uplimit);
 
 //Determing if February (28,or 29)  
 if (month == 1){
    if ( (year%100!=0) && (year%4==0) || (year%400==0)){
      FebNumberOfDays = 29;
    }else{
      FebNumberOfDays = 28;
    }
 }
 

 
 
 // names of months and week days.
 var monthNames = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November", "December"];
 var dayNames = ["SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI", "SAT"];
 var dayPerMonth = ["31", ""+FebNumberOfDays+"","31","30","31","30","31","31","30","31","30","31"]
 
 
 // days in previous month and next one , and day of week.
 var nextDate = new Date(nextMonth +' 1 ,'+year);
 var weekdays= nextDate.getDay();
 var weekdays2 = weekdays
 var numOfDays = dayPerMonth[month];
     
 
 
 
 // this leave a white space for days of pervious month.
 while (weekdays>0){
    htmlContent += "<div class='monthPre'></div>";
 
 // used in next loop.
     weekdays--;
 }
 
 // loop to build the calander body.
 while (counter<=uplimit){

     // When to start new line.
    if (weekdays2 > 6){
        weekdays2 = 0;
        htmlContent += "<div></div>";
    }
 
 
 
    // if counter is current day.
    // highlight current day using the CSS defined in header.
    if (counter == day){
        htmlContent +="<div class='dayNow' style='height:72px;width: 80px;border:1px solid #ff0000;margin-top: 1px;' onClick='currentdate("+counter+");'  onMouseOver='this.style.width=\"100px;\";' "+
        "onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\";'><br><span style='font-weight: 600; color: #058EFF;FONT-SIZE: 18px;'>"+counter+"</span><br><span style='font-size: 18px;font-weight: 600;color: #41738C;OPACITY: 0.8;'>"+dayNames[weekdays2]+"</span></div>";
    }else{
        htmlContent +="<div class='monthNow' style='height:72px;width: 80px;border:2px solid #eeeeee;margin-top: 1px;' onClick='currentdate("+counter+");' onMouseOver='this.style.border=\"1px solid #FF0000\";'"+
        " onMouseOut='this.style.border=\"2px solid #eeeeee\"'><br><span style='font-weight: 600; color: #058EFF;FONT-SIZE: 18px;'>"+counter+"</span><br><span style='font-size: 18px;font-weight: 600;color: #41738C;OPACITY: 0.8;'>"+dayNames[weekdays2]+"</span></div>";    
 
    }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
   
    weekdays2++;
    counter++;
 
 }
 
 
 
 // building the calendar html body.
 var calendarBody = "<div class='calendar'> <div class='monthNow'></div>";
 
 calendarBody += "";
 calendarBody += htmlContent;
 calendarBody += "";
 // set the content of div .
 document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML=calendarBody;
 
}
```

```css
.monthPre{
 color: gray;
 text-align: center;
}
.monthNow{
 color: blue;
 text-align: center;
}
.dayNow{
 border: 2px solid black;
 color: #FF0000;
 text-align: center;
}
.calendar td{
 htmlContent: 2px;
 width: 40px;
}
.monthNow th{
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
}
.dayNames{
 background: #0FF000;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload="displayCalendar()"> 
 

<input type = "date" id = "txtDate" onchange="displayCalendar()" value=""/>
 
<div id="calendar"></div> 


</body>
```

Hi Guys,

I was able to solve the query listed above and here is a running sample of Vertical Calendar wherein th current date is in the center and it will display four previous days and four next days with reference to current date.

The only problem with this code snippet is that it will also display negative values but the update will soon be provided.

Thankyou all :)

Comment: Wait, next Sunday is the 34th of August already? :-) Seems like your date calculation is still a bit off.